# Sharepoint 2013 - how to import Excel file and preserve "parent-child" reference?

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel-import

I faced with the following issue. I've got a CSV file with structure like:
ID|Name|ParentID
I would like to import this file into Sharepoint list (and create this list while importing) + I need to have the hierarchy ID/ParentID preserved w/o manual substitution right after the import. How can I have it done?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Import Spreadsheet list using your csv file, it will import the data of your file containing the column name.

However, one thing that you need to note is that the ID in your file will be ID1 as the SharePoint list has a built-in ID column.

[image]

Comment: Ok, but this is not exactly what I need. I need lookup field named, say, 'ParentRecord' populated automatically basing on ParentID column in the CSV being imported. How can I have it doe w/o coding?